# AppIcon xcassets not editable

Tags: xcode, asset-catalog

one of my project has a strange issue, I use xcassets for app icons, but xcode not show anything on the right panel.

what may cause this problem?

[image]

Comment: At the bottom right corner of the "empty view", do you have "Show Slicing" or "Show Overview"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the bottom right corner of the "empty view" from your screenshot, there is a "buttons bar" with show according to its states:

- [Show Slicing]
- [Zoom out] [Zoom In] [Show Overview]

Click on *[Show Overview]* to retrieve the wanted view.